Need guidance on how to resolve ERROR for running ArffHeaderSparkJob in the weka knowledge flow
 Error encountered for running ArffHeaderSparkJob in knowledge flow
Hi, I used the existing template in weka spark for creating an ArfHeader for spark using the hypothyroid sample data set in the knowledge flow environment. The ArffHeaderSparkJob node is connected to the text viewer in the flow.
When I ran the job for this workflow, I encountered an error [ERROR] ArffHeaderSparkJob$990429405|Stream closed"". I expected no error and that I would be able to view results in the text viewer.
Could you help to advise what is the root cause of the error and how I could fix it?
Image of the log file error . Many thanks.
I tried to look at the config for the affheaderSpark node to check that the paths were correct. Also checked the log file but could not ascertain what was the root cause of the problem but was not able to understand the error. Expected to be able to run the job successfully and be able to view results under the text viewer.
